# How to create a table in a single column format when document class is two column?

Tags: tables, two-column, elsarticle

I am writing a paper in two column format. In that paper, I would like to insert a table which is having single column format. How it can be done in LaTeX?

I have tried with following code:

```
\documentclass[final,5p,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphics}
\graphicspath{{F:/Figures/}}

\begin{document}
\section{1}
\section{2}
\section{3}

**\onecolumn
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\caption{Quality Metrics} 
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{cll} \hline

\end{tabular} 
\end{table}

\twocolumn
\section{Conclusions}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) We kindly suggest you to show a full [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) on what you have worked so far, so we can help you further with your table.

Comment: if you like to have table placed in one column of a document text, than remove `**\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` in given document example.

Comment: @Zarko Maybe we misunderstood OP's request, see Mico's comment below :):)

Comment: It should be `\usepackage{graphicx}`

Answer (score 2):

Hope you require the table should span both the coloumns, if yes, please refer to the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[final,5p,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{graphics}
\graphicspath{{F:/Figures/}} 
\begin{document}
\section{1} 
\section{2} 
\section{3}

\begin{table*}
 \centering \caption{Quality Metrics}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{cll}
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
```

If not match with your requirement, please clear your requirement clearly...

Comment: The question title explicitly says that the table should not span both columns, but be "single column format".

Comment: @TeXnician - I'd say the OP's write-up is quite ambiguous in this regard. For sure, I would have interpreted the objective exactly the way Mady Yuvi did.

Comment: @Mico Oh well, seems that I have misunderstood this interpretation.

Comment: @Mico I intended like TeXnician but now I'm very doubtful!

Comment: @CarLaTeX - Let's all keep our fingers crossed that the OP will weigh in soon and clarify his/her objectives.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what packages `elsarticle` requires, but if it uses `multicol` to invoke the columns, you may be in trouble, cf. the comments to [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18737/12558). For `multicol`, it's a problem with floats: They are not allowed in the `multicol` environment.

If just need the tabular, and not the float, for something like this
[image]

then you can use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}
first first first ... 
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|p{0.1\textwidth}|}
\hline 
 &  & \tabularnewline
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
second second second ...\columnbreak
third third third ...
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

**Edit based on comment:** You can also choose to not use the `multicol` package and invoke `twocolumn` as a document class option. If you just want the tabular, the above still works.

Comment: What do you mean with which package it requires? `twocolumn` is a document class option that's usually not bound to packages. The OP does not mention anything about `multicol`.

Comment: I mean that the `.cls` might include `\RequirePackage{multicol}` and use it to define the two column envronment, like the Springer Lecture Notes in Computer Science `llncs.cls` does e.g. for index. The OP doesn't mention that `elsarticle` is required, so I suggested `multicol` as it allows the freedom to e.g. not have the abstract in the two columns. That's how I've used it. I didn't know `twocolumn` was always available: Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: For the record: The `elsarticle` document class does *not* load the `multicol` package. Nowhere in `elsarticle.cls` does one find a `\RequirePackage{multicol}` directive.